# Business Natural Language for Ruby beginners

Tags: ruby, dsl

I would like to know where would you begin for doing natural language processing in Ruby. I am a [C# programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:236169%20%5Bc#%5D), and although I found this C# tutorial:
[Writing Your First Domain Specific Language](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSL.aspx), I would like to take this opportunity to learn the **Ruby** language, implementing something similar to:

- For question 1, the value is 3.0 if (question 1 answer is C,D), else 2.0.
- For question 3, the value is (question 1 value * 0.75) if (question 1 answer is B).
- For question 3, the value is (question 1 value * 0.50) if (question 1 answer is B) and (question 2 answer is C).
- For question 3, the default value is 3.0.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You might want to include examples of the actual source you want to parse. The description _"a somewhat more complex logic"_ could be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: @Bart: Sorry. I updated my question to reflect what I would actually want. :)

Comment: Those examples seem pretty structured to me. In other words, you could write a [CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and use [treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) (which can generate Ruby code!) to create a parser for you based on the grammar of your language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do natural language processing (you mention it in the text), I'd advise using [OpenNLP](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/) with JRuby. I did that last year and it worked out pretty well.

For DSLs, there are a ton of Ruby-specific tutorials on the web, just use your favorite search engine to find them. Book wise I'd recommend Russ Olson's "Eloquent Ruby" and Paola Perotta's "Metaprogramming Ruby". After those 2 books you should know everything you need to know about writing DSLs and have learned a lot of very good Ruby as a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at *DSLs in Action* (http://www.manning.com/ghosh/), as, though it is mostly covering Scala, he also discusses using Groovy, Clojure and Ruby, with examples of how to do a DSL in each of these languages.

He also does a great job in talking about how you may decide to approach designing/implementing your DSL.